# vim: modifying automatic textwrap in txt files?

Tags: vim

I use the firefox plugin pentadactyl for firefox, which adds a vim-like
structure to firefox. One nifty feature I found the other day is in textboxes
you can use ctrl-i to open vim and on saveclose it applies what was in the
file to the textbox... Sadly I can't figure out how to get the textwidth to
not default to 78 (Resulting in the funny formatting you see here).

I've modified my vimrc to tw=0 which seems to have no effect. The issue is not
unique to Pentadactyl, the tw setting is applied to 78 on any text file I open
it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the command "`:verbose set textwidth?`" (the question mark is part of the command).  It will tell you where the option was last set.

Comment: Yes, this worked. It showed that it was getting executed from vimrc_example

I deleted this, and my vimrc spit an error that vimrc_example didn't exist, and realized it apparently execs vimrc_example from stock file(probably a windows only thing but who knows). removed that line, no more errors, no more tw being set. thank you sir